# getting data from multiple tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

My goal is to get from the following tables - the user's unique group names and ids, the latest comments for the user's groups, the latest "done" article for the user's groups, the SUM of done articles, and total articles. Basically what is presented in the bottom sheet.

[image: problem]

**So far** I've managed to get the data from the groups table and from the articles, but I can't get the latest comment.

Here is my query

```
SELECT  `groups`.`name` ,  `groups`.`id` , (

SELECT MAX(  `articles`.`written` ) 
FROM  `articles` 
WHERE  `group` =  `groups`.`id` 
AND  `articles`.`done` =  '1'
) AS latestArt, (

SELECT MAX(  `comments`.`date_added` ) 
FROM  `comments` 
WHERE  `comments`.`article_id` =  `a`.`id` 
AND  `comments`.`active` =  '1'
) AS latestComm, SUM(  `a`.`done` =  '1' ) articlesAchieved, COUNT(  `a`.`id` ) AS totalArticles
FROM  `groups` 
LEFT JOIN  `articles` AS  `a` ON  `a`.`group` =  `groups`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN  `comments` AS  `c` ON  `c`.`note_id` =  `a`.`id` 
WHERE  `groups`.`user_id` =  '6'
AND  `n`.`active` =  '1'
GROUP BY  `groups`.`id`
```

I've also tried to get the data by joining everything to the `article` table but I wasn't successful with that either :(

Comment: Can you post your sample data in textual form? Images are great but it's impossible to work with data from it.

Comment: I'm trying to setup a sqlFiddle for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED** Your query might look like this

```sql
SELECT g.id group_id, g.name group_name,
       a.last_written, a.total_articles, a.total_done,
       c.last_comment
  FROM groups g LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT `group`, 
            MAX(CASE WHEN done = 1 THEN written END) last_written,
            COUNT(*) total_articles,
            SUM(done) total_done
      FROM articles
     WHERE active = 1
       AND user_id = 1
     GROUP BY `group`
) a 
    ON g.id = a.`group` LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT a.`group`,
           MAX(date_added) last_comment
      FROM commants c JOIN articles a
        ON c.article_id = a.id
     WHERE a.active = 1
       AND a.user_id = 1
     GROUP BY a.`group`
) c
    ON g.id = c.`group`
 WHERE  user_id =  1
```

Comment: I think that is it! There is one thing i can't sort out MAX(written) last_written has to be only the 'done' articles but if i add AND done='1' then the count(*) does not count all the articles. Any idea how to get it running. Thanks for the query, I would never be able to do it on my own, besides it is very quick!

Comment: You can try conditional aggregate. See updated answer. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: THIS IS MAD! Thanks guys for your help on this. Seriously I wouldn't be able to do it on my own. This was great!

Comment: Thanks, I added the sort for the user at the bottom.

Comment: @Ando do you want this query to work only for a particular `user_id` or you want to sort (meaning order by) `user_id`?

Comment: I want it only for the particular user_id

Comment: Then you better add a separate condition in each subquery, because they (subqueries) are evaluated and executed independently before being joined with `groups`. Result is the same but execution plan and time of execution are different. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Should i keep the bottom line then? Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Yes you should keep it because in your case outer `LEFT` joins are used.

Comment: can I ask you one more question since this is really complicated for my skills. You see, I have a group=0 user_id=0 which is the default group if no category has been selected. Is there a simple way to include the articles which are in the default 0 cat and for 0 user?

Comment: I didn't exactly understand how you want it, but you can try to change  `user_id =  1` to `user_id IN(0, 1)` in both subqueries and the outer select.

Comment: Thanks Peterm! You've been very helpful. I definitely learned a lot from this query. I hope it gets the concept across to other members.